# how to reset vscode to default setting and configurations

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

Hello guys so I am new to web programming currently learning HTML and CSS and I am using VSCode but my problem is ( i am a newbie) when I try to run the HTML and CSS code I get this file `launch.json` and it doesn't show me the page I am working on how to fix this I uninstalled and installed but still the same issue I think I messed up with the configuration [this is when I run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUxwv.png) 
[this how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkCGP.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way, for this moment is to install the [liveserver](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) plugin to your `VSCode` editor, Here you have [link](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=vscode%20liveserver) to many tutorials how to do this and much more..;-) and then do a decent review of the conventions and rules of [web development](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn) Good Luck, and **Keep calm and do not stop coding** !